# Closed and open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, sequences-and-series, analysis

By regarding the real numbers with their natural topology, my textbook says, that:

$$ \left\{2 \pi n+\frac{1}{n}\;\bigg|\;n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$

is closed, which i understand, as every sequence in $ \mathbb{R}$ has its limit in this set.

But by regarding $$ \left\{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\;\Big|\;n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$ my textbook says, that this is open and i do not see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is closed as it is a set of discrete points.

Two is not closed because it doesn't contain the limit point 0.

It is not open though. Consider the point sin(1).

"Sets are not doors".

Answer (score 0):

I understand your confusion. The statement is not true! If it *were* true, then the preimage of that set under the continuous function $\sin:[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\to[-1,1]$ would be open, which it is not.

However, we can *also* say that the second set is not closed, because then the preimage of that set under the continuous function $\sin:[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\to[-1,1]$ would be closed, which it is not.

It is possible for a set to be neither open nor closed. $[0,1)$ is a good example of a subset of $\Bbb R$ that is neither open nor closed.